# Воспроизведение потокового видео из файла базы данных

Tags: c#, sql-server, потоки-данных, videoview

Необходимо показывать потоковое видео из файла базы данных `MSSQL` (файл сам сохранён через `FILESTREAM`). Проект на `C# (.Net 4.0, WPF)`. Можно было бы конечно сначала сохранять из БД на жесткий диск, но как-то это нехорошо и ждать придётся. Хочется воспроизводить сразу и без загрузки полного файла. Сама база данных может быть, как локальной, так и на удалённой.

В общем, как-то надо показывать потоковое видео, которое было записано и сжато при помощи `DirectShow`.`

Какие есть варианты решений?

Я пока сам смог придумать только, чтобы:

- создавать два потока
- один пишет файл на диск из базы данных и отображает подгрузку
- второй воcпроизводит поток тем же `DirectShow`.

Здесь потребуется продумать синхронизацию этих двух потоков, да и желательно не превышать размер буфера на диске. (например можно писать в два файла ограниченного размера и подменять их при воспроизведении).

Возможно есть какие-то более изящные и интересные решения? А-ля `MediaElement` (не нравится из-за того, что требует `WMP10`).

Программисты, поделитесь опытом! Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вы можете получить доступ непосредственно к данным FILESTREAM, не записывая их на диск. Пример есть тут: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/cc716724(v=vs.100).aspx
Описан способ работы через `SqlFileStream`.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko Могу,например, писать из Filstream в поток. Это да. Но вопрос сейчас, как этот поток показывать DirectShow. DirectShow может работать с устройством или файлом в качестве источника. Знаю, что библиотеки и фильтры ffmpeg могут работать с потоком (есть примеры с потоковым видео из интернета). Конкретно фильтр movie из ffmpeg способен захватывать поток. Но сможет ли он работать с DirectShow и захватить поток из памяти (Stream).

Comment: Обязательно нужно показывать через DirectShow? Я с ним не работал никогда. Интернет подсказывает, что такая возможность там есть, но она реализуется не тривиально: необходимо разработать фильтр, скорее всего на C++, который сможет читать данные из SQL и отдавать их в DirectShow. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0c96961b-8679-4bd7-b3f9-1a6f33ae3554/c-playing-video-from-a-memory-stream-using-directshow-quartzdll?forum=windowsdirectshowdevelopment

Comment: Как вариант можете попробовать BoxedApp, который позволяет "создавать" фейковые файлы или ключи реестра. http://www.boxedapp.com/boxedappsdk/

Comment: @MarkShevchenko  DirectShow использовать хочется, потому как для записи его использовал, и для воспроизведения логично воспользоваться тем же инструментом. Проблема только с захватом.   BoxedApp можно использовать правда преимуществ особенных не вижу, можно и просто во временный файл писать в папку с программой.

Comment: Насколько я понял, BoxedApp позволяет избавиться от записи/чтения через файловую систему, и работать напрямую.